# python CSV intelligent parser and column matching

Tags: python, csv, matching, dynamic-columns

I've couple of thousands of CSV files where most of them have following columns

```
threadSubject
bccList
sender_name
recipient_names
sender  
dateReceived
date    
recipients
subject
```

Unfortunately depending on the CSV file each column if it is present might be at different columnt number therefore complicating parsing.

What I need to do is extract from the input CSV files only these selected columns and put them all into single output file.

I'm new to python and am sure there's perfectly easy way to achieve this but I can't figure it out.
I'm not sure if should use Pandas or other mechanism.

In logical code it should work more or less like this.

```
for file in (all files in current folder); do
  open file;
  get header and find out at which positions are interesting columns 
  #or match by column name;

  dump interesting columns into output file in the right order;
  close file;
done
```

The tricky part of me is `get header...`

Would any of you have any advise how to do it in smart pythonic way?

I thought about bash and parse it manually, but thought it might be a good idea to learn how to do it in python with your help.

p.s. background of it is that I need to go through all emails for last 5 years and find out at what time was sent out first email and last email during each day. The CSVs I've were created based on Thunderbird MSF files using Mork tool. Once I'll have this CSV parsing done, I'll need to find out easy way to get time of first email and last email on the same day. BUt this is another story.

Thanks in advance for all advises.

Comment: I highly suggest looking into the pandas library and parsing your files by importing them as dataframes and performing manipulations there, the column order will no longer matter if you parse it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column names are the same in all the files , use csv.DictReader to do the job.

[Python csv.DictReader Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

You can reference the field names directly rather than the column number.

```
    import csv
    file = open('Path_to_file','rb')
    for record in csv.DictReader(file):
        print record['Column_Name']
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks. This is one part of equation.

Sorryy for dumb question, but how then do I merge selected columns from multiple files and save them into single file? I need to merge all selected columns row by row.

I've read a bit on python but still am a bit confused :(
It's so different from C, bash, etc. and the main problem for me is that I didn't used to write in python therefore do not know all the concepts ;(

Would any of you please give me some more hints with example?

THanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that out of interesting columns not all of them are in each file. How do I skip empty fields and not cause an error on the console?

Comment: You'll have to maintain referential integrity when merging data across data sets. The cardinality of the relationship might be 1-1 or 1-M or M-M - in that increasing order of complexity to handle them. Do you have common fields (say a key column like email message ID) across files that will help you match data ?

Comment: Yes, there is expected to be uniq ID. What I want to do is from msf files generate normal table with date/time of each email and then as next step find out first and last email for each of the day. This is required for exercise to count number of hours I've spent working for each day taking as confirmation of beginning/end of the day, email sent.